# Рандомное присвоение текста одной из кнопок

Tags: c#

Например: у меня есть 4 кнопки. Хочу, чтобы по рандому, тексту одного из этих кнопок присвоился "Х". Как сделать? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Расскажите, пожалуйста, что вы пробовали, и на каком из этапов возникли вопросы.

Comment: создаю игру крестики нолики, с участием компьютера и вот для хода компьютера мне нужен рандом, чтобы он сделал ход в одном из перечисленных клеток, например 1, 3, 7, 9. Только вот не знаю как сделать рандом КНОПОК =/ @eigenein

Comment: Поместите кнопки в массив и выберите случайный элемент массива.

Comment: Рандом как я прочитал работает с диапазоном. Например A.Next(10), А будет меняться от 0 - 10. Но мне же нужно либо Х, либо О

Answer (score 3):

Random.Next(10) вернёт случайное число в пределах **от 0 до 9**. Если нужно всего два варианта, то и сделайте их два:

```
char c = random.Next(2) == 0 ? 'X' : 'O';
```

Comment: @shad а как сделать это с кнопками? Ну я хочу тексту кнопки присвоить это все

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример случайного выбора контрола, и попытка присвоить его свойству Text значения X. В этом примере нет проверки на тип контрола,

```
this.Controls[new Random().Next(0,3)].Text = "X";
```

Написано на коленке, работоспособность не проверял, но смысл, думаю, понятен

Comment: Вы наверняка имели ввиду [Random.Next()][1].


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx

Comment: Точно! Спасибо, исправил